# Manifestation merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, runtime-error

I've checked the merged manifest to find these errors

(Note that I'm a beginner android developer so every problem in android studio seems like the end of the world to me. Please help me solve this error, thanks in advance)

```
ERROR: tools:replace specified at line:6 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified App_Name.app main manifest (this file), line 5
ERROR: Validation failed, exiting App_Name.app main manifest (this file)
```

My Manifest.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.syddhoo.bookapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BookApp"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you really need `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">`?

Comment: I didn't add it. I'll try removing that line and see if my problem is fixed.